# create a query with combobob values in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query in access where i want to compare a text column value to a combo value

```
SELECT NAME.ID, NAME.V_name, NAME.Gender, NAME.V_center, NAME.BoxNo, NAME.SerinBox 
FROM NAME
WHERE ((cint([Forms]![Name]![Combo75].value) >= 2020-cint(left([name.id])))
  and (cint([Forms]![Name]![Combo77].value) <= 2020-cint(left([name.id]))));
```

getting error in SQL statement, couldn't figure it out.
[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s00pF.png)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: added the error image to the quesion , wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear:

> Wrong number of arguments . . .

The code in question is:

```
left([name.id])
```

The [`left()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/left-function-d5897bf6-91f5-4bf8-853a-b63d7de09681) function takes two arguments.  The second is how many characters to return.